# Support on tiny leg

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures

When slicing with Cura, a "flying" support was added. Why would it happen and how to fix it?

Top-side view:
[image]

Bottom-side view:
[image]

Bottom view:
[image]

As expected, the support failed.

Note, the images are flow maps. Support is colored red. I used lines pattern for support. Both support and inner walls are printer on 60 mm/s, so they are both red. The green you see under the support is a support base. But, for some reason it's disconnected from the support.

Answer (score 2):

In one-off cases like this, the best solution is adding a manual support.

1. Select the part. Select 'support blocker' from the right menu, then click somewhere on the part - a semi-transparent cube will be added.

[image: created support blocker]

2. Translate, Scale and Rotate the cube to the shape of the support: connecting the build plate with the critical point. Make it embed the problem point with a good margin - Cura will isolate it from the actual print body automatically, so don't worry about it merging with it.

[image: blocker placed at target location]

3. Change its type to 'Print as Support' using the 'Per Model Settings'

[image: Manual support]

That way you can support anything Cura fails to support automatically.

Additionally, I found using Tree Supports works vastly better than standard supports in great most cases - not just with 'organic' models - they work quite well with 'technical' models where you need to support a large flat area, and tend to succeed in cases where normal supports fail miserably.